# .htaccess Redirect Subfolder list Recursive towards new Domain

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Relocated website to new domain. The old domain will be used for other purposes so what i need to do is to redirect ~800 Subfolders (users profiles) recursive towards the new url.

I could use something like this

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/user/(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/user/$1
```

This will redirect all sub pages / folders to this user but not if someone visit old-domain.com/user.

How can i redirect both all the specific ~800 subfolder + recursive within the same line ( for every profile )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tweak your regex like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/user(/.*)?$ http://new-domain.com/user$1
```

This will also redirect `old-domain.com/user` to `new-domain.com/user`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to just do:

```
Redirect 301 /user http://new-domain.com/user
```

Comment: But would that redirect recursive ?

Comment: @MathiasÅsberg not as long as new-domain.com is different from old-domain.com. It does essentially the same thing as the `RedirectMatch` except without any regular expressions.